# How would you describe something cool and old that you just discovered?

Tags: expressions, adjectives, synonyms

I **recently** discovered a piece of entertainment media that's cool, but old - think Fresh Prince of Bel-Air. When I want to tell my friends about the show, I can't say:

> "Hey guys, I just found a *cool new thing*!"

(because it's not new)

I want to emphasize on the short timeframe between the discovery of the show and the time of speech, but because of English adjective order, the following doesn't fly:

> "Hey guys, I just found a *new cool thing*!"

Is there a short and simple way to express what I want to say?

Answer (score 2):

I would use [classic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/classic).

The first definition fits your case (both for the adjective and the noun):

> (noun) A work of art of recognized and established value.
>   (adjective) Judged over a period of time to be of the highest quality and outstanding of its kind.

Please note the difference in adjectives:

- Classical = pertaining to Roman or ancient Greek culture; or classical music.
- Classic = something that is old but still appreciated or admired

There may be other descriptions that are better suited in specific contexts; but you provided no real context.
If it's about a work of art (music, theater, ...) that is still considered amazing today; I would call it an [evergreen](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/evergreen).

> (noun) A person or thing of enduring freshness, success, or popularity.
>   (adjective) Having an enduring freshness, success, or popularity.

However, for e.g. a movie, car or ideology, I would still prefer using "classic". It just sounds better to my ears, though that may be too subjective.

Comment: Thanks! Though I mentioned that I want to emphasize on the timeframe of the discovery (note the bolded "recently" - though it seems like it's not enough), where timeframe here means the time between the "discovery" and the time of speech, not the time between the publishing of the work and the "discovery".

Comment: @peco When you say you "recently discovered a classic", you are saying everything you want to. The thing you discovered is amazing, it has been around for a while, but you have only recently heard about it (or started appreciating it).

Comment: @peco: If you are trying to describe the timeframe of _the act of discovering_ rather than _the discovered object_, you have to use an adverb (which modifies the verb); as opposed to an adjective (which modifies the noun). When you say "I discovered a new thing", you are not talking about the discovery being new, but the thing itself being new.

Comment: Fair enough! I was looking to avoid using the adverb because it sounds dragged out, but if there's no terser way of saying it then I'll go ahead and accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

guys, I just found a ***Golden Oldie***  From the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/79775?redirectedFrom=golden+oldie#eid2835336)

> golden oldie  n. colloq.  (a) a familiar old song, film, etc., that
>   remains popular and is still regarded with affection;  (b) a popular
>   older or elderly person; esp. a veteran performer, etc., who retains
>   his or her popularity or appeal.
>
> 1966   Time 2 Dec. 46   The platter..promises to become what the
>   deejays call a ‘Golden Oldie’.
>
> 1971   Amer. Polit. Sci. Rev. 65 781/1   New faces and golden oldies
>   alike.
>
> 1995   Snooker Scene May 16/1   While one veteran was being
>   overwhelmed by a youthful opponent another golden oldie, Denis Taylor,
>   showed characteristic determination.
>
> 2000   A. Calcutt Brit Cult 151/1   Terrestrial broadcasters have got
>   in on the act also, recognising that ‘rpt’ [i.e. repeat] need not be a
>   dirty word if the programme in question can be presented as a ‘golden
>   oldie’

(Entry given in full, because you may not be able to access the link.)

Answer (score 0):

"Hey, guys, I just found some **nostalgia**!"

Nostalgia has several meanings.  It refers to [A sentimental longing or wistful affection for a period in the past. (Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nostalgia)  It is also used to refer to items [that elicit or display nostalgia.  (Dictionary.com)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nostalgia)

This has become a popular term for old-fashioned items and old movies and TV shows.  Retailers call such items "nostalgia" and often have a category of that name to search for it.  TV broadcasters also refer to old movies and shows as "nostalgia".

Comment: Recency is a word.